# Google Analytics Sign In with user and password

Tags: java, json, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing an app in java/sacala to provide to differents clients use their google analytics info. But the only way I found to connect to get the info is using .p12 certificate or client_secret.json.
Is it possible to connect just with user and password like a regular login in google. (maybe with the regular login you can get the .p12 or the json without enter to analytics console)
Because I saw in some apps like tableau this feature but I didn´t find documentation about that in google.

Thanks

Comment: It's not ideal to have users enter their Google credentials on your app because it opens up security issues. Try to read their [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the [Java Install Application Hello World example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-java). When the user runs your application they will be prompted to sign in and authorize your application to access their data.

It also helps to take a look at the the [OAuth scenarios](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios).

If you are trying to hard code the username and password into an application, this will not work for obvious security reasons. If that is your intent you should use a service account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to enter or save google credentials on my app. I saw some apps that opens google login screen and then they are getting analytics data without .p12, jason and avoinding all the configuration in the analitycs developer console. But I couldn't find a good documentation or example of that. Always use .p12, json.